# c# unity serializatiom deserialization

Tags: c#, serialization, unity

I am making some modifies in a complex c# unity project. Generally c# project generates a dll file and another unity project is using it. Serialization and deserialization operations works on Android, Mac and Windows but not on IOS. Also newtonsoft version should be upper than 11, because otherwise it affects another parts of the project and newtonsoft for unity and json .net for unity libraries developed woth lower version of newtonsoft so it doesnt work on my project. Are there any ideas about it?